# Количество столбцов в bootstrap3

Tags: bootstrap

несмотря на то, что bootstrap3 не самый новый фреймворк, тематических форумов или другого саппорта в сети почти нет. поэтому ещё раз попробую попытать счастья здесь

проблема в следующем. есть [страничка](http://jsfiddle.net/S2rnm/846/), которая состоит из 3 блоков, равномерно растянутых по ширине страницы. блоки расположены в ряд. ряд перестраивается в зависимости от мобильного устройства, с которого смотрит страничку посетитель(можно изменить ширину окна браузера или понажимать CTRL  +  "-" чтобы увидеть перестройку блоков).

хотелось бы создать подобную страничку из 5 блоков. трудность в том, что в bootstrap шаблон 12-колоночный. а 12 не делится на 5

на стек оверфлоу не смогли ответить на этот вопрос

Comment: Смещение с помощью offset не подойдет? Будет 5 колонок шириной по 2 с отступом

Comment: не подойдёт. дело в том, что мои блоки должны быть выровнены по краям. то есть левый прилипает к левому, правый - к правому

Answer (score 1):

Ну не делится у тебя 12 на 5. Сделай тогда col-sm-2 и растяни их через display:flex. Появились проблемы с адаптивностью? Если да, тогда переделай полностью на display:grid. Там хоть 100500 колонок делай, растянутся по всей ширине и будут адаптивными.

Answer (score 1):

Можно адаптировать bootstrap под ваши нужды
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Делаем сетку, которая делиться на 5

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#grid-system

По умолчанию -  `@grid-columns - 12`

Например, вместо 12 ставим - 60